# Did Tatooine ever have a Senator?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, tatooine

Did Tatooine ever have a Senator in the Imperial or New Republic Senates (Canon or Legends)?

I know that they didn't have a Republic Senator due to it being in Hutt space, but in *Kenobi* there is an Imperial garrison there, so I wasn't certain if it had a governor or senator.

Comment: I don't have time to do the research atm, but if I remember correctly, Tatooine is in the Arkanis System and at least in the New Republic era, Arkanis is represented by a senator named Carise Sindian. I know generally senators represent their whole sector so it may be safe to assume she represented Tatooine as well since it's in the same sector.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, an Imperial garrison didn't require a senator, but rather a governor or a military commander. In Legends, indeed, [Tour Aryon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tour_Aryon) was the Imperial governor of Tatooine during the events of the *Episode IV*. In addition, the garrison on Tatooine was run by [an unidentified Imperial commander](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_Imperial_commander_(Tatooine)).

Comment: The Senate was dissolved near the start of *Episode IV* with the regional governors taking direct control over the territories. So I don't know that Tour Aryon being the regional governor in charge of Tatooine during the events of that film is very compelling evidence that Tatooine lacked a senator before then.

Answer (score -1):

No. As part of the Outer Rim, Tatooine has no real political standings, except Imperial occupation. Tatooine is run by the Hutts, who don't abide by the Galactic Republic or The Empire, unless occupation has occurred.